# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '!', expecting T_STRING

Tags: parsing, escaping

Sorta a newbie to PHP so please excuse this simple question.
I'm trying to connect to my mysql db where my password happens to have an exclamation mark in it.

I've searched and while this general parsing error appears often in Stack Ovedrflow, I've tried escaping my exclamation mark in my password, but it still has this error.

I'm using `TextEditor` and saving as `txt` (no `richtext`) and FTP'ing in ASCII. I have the file as `.php` and view it live on the web, not local. Oh, also the example I was working with did not include the end `?>` tag, so it's missing.

Here's the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '!', expecting T_STRING in
>   /home/content/29/9326929/html/dragonfly/php_mysql_test.php on line 8

Here's the code:

```
<?php
//Variables for connecting to your database.
//These variable values come from your hosting account.
$hostname = "xxxxxxx";
$username = "xxxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxxx";

$password = “mypassword!”;
$usertable = “table_name”;
$yourfield = "field_name";

mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE ("Unable to
connect to database! Please try again later.");
mysql_select_db($dbname);
```

Comment: `"` != `”` You use different "'s thoughout the code.

Comment: Hi Rangad, Thanks so much for catching that. I have no idea how there can even be two different double quotes. Very strange. I corrected that and that fixed the issue. Thanks! I'm not sure of Stackoverflow protocol. Because now of course the socket has connected but now I get an access denied warning message!

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for      user 'xxxxxx'@'1.2.3.4' (using password: YES) in /home/content/29/9326929/html/abc/php_mysql_test.php on line 15
Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.

Maybe its an issue with my hosting provider?

Comment: You shouldn't be using the mysql_* functions in the first place. These functions are deprecated and removed in the next major version of php (to be released in q4 this year). Look into PDO and/or mysql**i**. But you are right, you are likely using the wrong credentials or something similar. However, if you have a new question create a new question (but search first, if a similar question already exists). Regarding the original issue: You are using an editor that in its current configuration isn't ment for programming.

Comment: Hi Rangad. Thanks so much for those excellent tips and recommendations. I really appreciated it. I will immediately switch over to another platform like Coda or even TextWrangler. I was given a heads up that apparently I'm trying to login when I'm already working within my /wordpress folder (which has mysql access)... perhaps this is causing the conflict. I will close this issue. Thanks again!

Comment: Background: I'm strictly trying to pull data to use within PHP. After I fixed above double quote issue my original issue stood, that I was not able to properly make a db connection (not remote). Below is proper method.

    require_once('wp-config.php');                             //link to WP db via WP config file
    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);      //setup connection with the variable names for wp-config